# Синхронизация проекта в eclipse между пк

Tags: eclipse, синхронизация

Я с другом хочу делать программу на eclipse IDE, но меня интересует - можно ли синхронизировать один проект на нескольких пк, ну например на одном пк сделали класс Test, а на втором пк тоже?

Comment: Конечно можно, используйте mercurial или git.

Comment: См. комментарий выше. Наиболее популярный инструмент -- площадка [github](https://github.com). Довольно легкая в изучении и использовании.